# C# base16 encoded SHA256 string function not returning expected result

Tags: c#, hex, sha256, amazon-mws

I have a function that is attempting to return a lower case base 16 encoded hash of a request body for signing the AWS API, as detailed in the hashed payload section [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html).

Given the following JSON string -

```
{
  "shipTo": {
    "name": "A3",
    "addressLine1": "SWA Test Account",
    "addressLine2": "SWA Test Account",
    "addressLine3": "SWA Test Account",
    "stateOrRegion": "",
    "postalCode": "DN1 1QZ",
    "city": "Doncaster",
    "countryCode": "GB",
    "email": "test+test@amazon.com",
    "phoneNumber": "444-444-4444"
  },
  "shipFrom": {
    "name": "A1",
    "addressLine1": "4 Neal Street",
    "stateOrRegion": "",
    "postalCode": "WC2H 9QL",
    "city": "London",
    "countryCode": "GB",
    "email": "test+test@amazon.com",
    "phoneNumber": "444-444-4444"
  },
  "packages": [
    {
      "dimensions": {
        "length": 3.14,
        "width": 3.14,
        "height": 3.14,
        "unit": "INCH"
      },
      "weight": {
        "unit": "KILOGRAM",
        "value": 3.14159
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "quantity": 1,
          "itemIdentifier": "V-02",
          "description": "Sundries",
          "isHazmat": false,
          "weight": {
            "unit": "KILOGRAM",
            "value": 1.14159
          }
        },
        {
          "quantity": 1,
          "itemIdentifier": "V-01",
          "description": "Sundries",
          "isHazmat": false,
          "weight": {
            "unit": "KILOGRAM",
            "value": 1.14159
          }
        }
      ],
      "insuredValue": {
        "unit": "GBP",
        "value": 29.98
      },
      "packageClientReferenceId": "abcd"
    }
  ],
  "channelDetails": {
    "channelType": "EXTERNAL"
  }
}
```

I am expecting a return value of `71d826b7bab4af808f73033e81154bce32fed66f1270393d8b0fa05839a6fb29` as displayed in successful postman calls for the same JSON value.

However, I am getting a value of `16f1382cc1db6988693b66e49597811e46f4210c284c82cbc37b6a9f58c61bf5`, which throws off subsequent signing values, and causes the call to fail.

Here is the function that takes the JSON string and returns the hash -

```
public static string HashRequestBody(string stringToHash)
{
    byte[] hashedBytes = new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToHash));
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < hashedBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hashedBytes[i].ToString("x2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

What would be causing the differences in hashed payload values in my code as opposed to the Postman call for the same request body?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the hash was different due to the line breaks included in my JSON object.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39521676/3351431), but the short of it is Microsoft uses \r\n for line breaks by default, and the hash Amazon is calculating is using only \n as a line break.

I resolved this by serializing the object to a string and replacing \r\n with the expected \n values, like so:

`body = Regex.Replace(body, @"\r\n?|\n", "\n");`